# log in failure with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have been using the following selenium code with python to log into sites. Recently,however, it has stopped working. There are no error messages, the log in page just keeps coming up with empty data fields.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
import sys

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\george\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://xxxxx')
elem=driver.find_element_by_id ("loginId")
elem.send_keys('xxxxx')
elem=driver.find_element_by_id ("lastName")
elem.send_keys('xxxxx')
elem=driver.find_element_by_id ("password")
elem.send_keys('xxxx')
elem=driver.find_element_by_id("button_login").click()
```

Comment: have you considered the possibility that your username and/or password has become invalid?

Comment: YES, and the gas tank is full.